# Auth0 .Net Core 5 API Keep returning 401-Unauthorirezd

Tags: c#, auth0, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm trying to secure a .Net Core 5 API, with Auth0.

The API keep returning me "401 Unauthorized".
I'm testing the API with Postman Windows App.

I'm messing with the default API template WeatherForecast from Visual Studio 2019.

Calling the public method/EndPoint works fine (http://localhost:20741/WeatherForecast/public).

I'm requesting a token with Postman, which I supply to the GET Request as a Bearer Token.
But When I call the private endpoint (http://localhost:20741/WeatherForecast/private)
I keep getting the 401 error.

I've downloaded the sample .Net Core 3.0 project from Auth0 web site and private or public endpoints work fine. I'm using the same Audience and Authority on both project.
I think it has something to do the .Net Core 5 config.

```
namespace AuthWebApplication1
{
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
    using WebAPIApplication;

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "AuthWebApplication1", Version = "v1" });
            });

            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200")
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });

            string domain = $"https://dev-***2b.us.auth0.com/";
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = domain;
                    options.Audience = "https://localhost:44349/";
                });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("read:messages", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new HasScopeRequirement("read:messages", domain)));
            });

            // register the scope authorization handler
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, HasScopeHandler>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "AuthWebApplication1 v1"));
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
namespace AuthWebApplication1.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("public")]
        public IActionResult Public()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                Message = "Hello from a public endpoint! You don't need to be authenticated to see this."
            });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("private")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Private()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                Message = "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated to see this."
            });
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("private-scoped")]
        [Authorize("read:messages")]
        public IActionResult Scoped()
        {
            return Ok(new
            {
                Message = "Hello from a private endpoint! You need to be authenticated and have a scope of read:messages to see this."
            });
        }

        [HttpGet("claims")]
        public IActionResult Claims()
        {
            return Ok(User.Claims.Select(c =>
                new
                {
                    c.Type,
                    c.Value
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   // More Code ..

   //*************************
   // replace this
   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
   });
   //*************************

   //*************************
   // with this
   app.UseMvc(routes =>
   {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
   //*************************
   // some more code
}
```

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // some code
   //*************************
   // add this
   services.AddMvc(x => x.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
   //*************************
   // some more code
}
```